# Php If multiple variables

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to make a general if for some variables that i have in my database. Let's say that we have the next variables and values:

```
$var1 = "abc";
$var2 = "n/a";
$var3 = "das";
$var4 = "n/a";
```

My if statement must include all these variables, check which variables contain "n/a" and for every variable that contain "n/a" the script must make another variable `$var21 = "Not Available"`. Is that possible?

Comment: you can set up a default value inside your database. Maybe it will do the trick

Comment: Sure it's possible - why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not use `variable variables`, just due to personal preference. If you're masochistic, [you can certainly try](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

I'd create an extra hash instead. <strike>This would remove the need for an if-statement as well</strike>. :)

```
$descriptions = array(
    "n/a" => "Not Available",
    "brb" => "Be Right Back",
    "iee" => "I'm easily extendable"
);
```

Then when you need the text for a particular key you can just type

```
$descriptive_text = $descriptions[$var1];
```

**Updated:**

To set it to the original if there is no value in `$descriptions`, do the following:

```
$descriptive_text = (is_null($descriptions[$var1])) ? $var1 : $descriptions[$var1];
```

Comment: and if the variable not contains "n/a" how can i go with the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrays for this.

```
$array = array("abc", "n/a", "das", "n/a");
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
 if($value == "n/a")
 {
  echo "Do Something!";
 }
}
```

See also: [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).